# emulator shows unfortunately, myapp has stopped

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-logcat

when i run my application emulator simply says "unfortunately,myapp has stopped".
 the logcat throws error.
my logcat error

```
04-21 15:24:13.661: I/Process(25846): Sending signal. PID: 25846 SIG: 9
04-21 15:24:34.572: D/AndroidRuntime(25911): Shutting down VM
04-21 15:24:34.572: W/dalvikvm(25911): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-21 15:24:34.592: E/AndroidRuntime(25911): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-21 15:24:34.592: E/AndroidRuntime(25911): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.loga/com.example.loga.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-21 15:24:34.592: E/AndroidRuntime(25911):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-21 15:24:34.592: E/AndroidRuntime(25911):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-21 15:24:34.592: E/AndroidRuntime(25911):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-21 15:24:34.592: E/AndroidRuntime(25911):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-21 15:24:34.592: E/AndroidRuntime(25911):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-21 15:24:34.592: E/AndroidRuntime(25911):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-21 15:24:34.592: E/AndroidRuntime(25911):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-21 15:24:34.592: E/AndroidRuntime(25911):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-21 15:24:34.592: E/AndroidRuntime(25911):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-21 15:24:34.592: E/AndroidRuntime(25911):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-21 15:24:34.592: E/AndroidRuntime(25911):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-21 15:24:34.592: E/AndroidRuntime(25911):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-21 15:24:34.592: E/AndroidRuntime(25911): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-21 15:24:34.592: E/AndroidRuntime(25911):    at com.example.loga.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
04-21 15:24:34.592: E/AndroidRuntime(25911):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-21 15:24:34.592: E/AndroidRuntime(25911):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-21 15:24:34.592: E/AndroidRuntime(25911):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-21 15:24:34.592: E/AndroidRuntime(25911):    ... 11 more
04-21 15:24:37.425: I/Process(25911): Sending signal. PID: 25911 SIG: 9
04-21 15:24:42.581: D/AndroidRuntime(25927): Shutting down VM
04-21 15:24:42.581: W/dalvikvm(25927): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-21 15:24:42.602: E/AndroidRuntime(25927): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-21 15:24:42.602: E/AndroidRuntime(25927): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.loga/com.example.loga.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-21 15:24:42.602: E/AndroidRuntime(25927):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-21 15:24:42.602: E/AndroidRuntime(25927):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-21 15:24:42.602: E/AndroidRuntime(25927):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-21 15:24:42.602: E/AndroidRuntime(25927):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-21 15:24:42.602: E/AndroidRuntime(25927):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-21 15:24:42.602: E/AndroidRuntime(25927):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-21 15:24:42.602: E/AndroidRuntime(25927):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-21 15:24:42.602: E/AndroidRuntime(25927):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-21 15:24:42.602: E/AndroidRuntime(25927):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-21 15:24:42.602: E/AndroidRuntime(25927):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-21 15:24:42.602: E/AndroidRuntime(25927):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-21 15:24:42.602: E/AndroidRuntime(25927):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-21 15:24:42.602: E/AndroidRuntime(25927): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-21 15:24:42.602: E/AndroidRuntime(25927):    at com.example.loga.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
04-21 15:24:42.602: E/AndroidRuntime(25927):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-21 15:24:42.602: E/AndroidRuntime(25927):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-21 15:24:42.602: E/AndroidRuntime(25927):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-21 15:24:42.602: E/AndroidRuntime(25927):    ... 11 more
04-21 15:24:46.051: I/Process(25927): Sending signal. PID: 25927 SIG: 9
04-21 15:28:28.302: E/Trace(26031): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-21 15:28:29.192: D/AndroidRuntime(26031): Shutting down VM
04-21 15:28:29.192: W/dalvikvm(26031): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-21 15:28:29.202: E/AndroidRuntime(26031): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-21 15:28:29.202: E/AndroidRuntime(26031): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.loga/com.example.loga.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-21 15:28:29.202: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-21 15:28:29.202: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-21 15:28:29.202: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-21 15:28:29.202: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-21 15:28:29.202: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-21 15:28:29.202: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-21 15:28:29.202: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-21 15:28:29.202: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-21 15:28:29.202: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-21 15:28:29.202: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-21 15:28:29.202: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-21 15:28:29.202: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-21 15:28:29.202: E/AndroidRuntime(26031): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-21 15:28:29.202: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at com.example.loga.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
04-21 15:28:29.202: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-21 15:28:29.202: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-21 15:28:29.202: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-21 15:28:29.202: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    ... 11 more
```

i dont know where actually it went wrong but no error in coding.
my .java file is

```
package com.example.loga;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;



import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;



import android.app.ProgressDialog;


import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class Login extends Activity {

     private ProgressDialog pDialog;

     JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        EditText inputpw;


        private static String url_logincheck = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/logincheck.php";
        // JSON Node names
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";





    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
         // Edit Text
        inputpw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                new check().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
        return true;
    }
    class check extends AsyncTask<String, String,String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Validating....");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String pw = inputpw.getText().toString();


            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pw",pw));



            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_logincheck,
                    "POST", params);
            // check log cat for response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    AlertDialog alertDialog;
                    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("password verification..");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("success.!!");
                    alertDialog.show();
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
             }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            return null;

        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

}
```

my activity_login.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Login" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:text="@string/password"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="136dp"
        android:text="@string/click" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

my MainActivity.java file is:

```
package com.example.loga;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button button1,button2,button3,button4;
    final Context context = this;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
         button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
         button3=  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
         button4=  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
         button1.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
         button2.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
         button3.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
         button4.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
           switch(v.getId()) {
               case R.id.button1:
               // do stuff
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

                button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity1.class);
                                       startActivity(intent);   
                    }
                });
               break;
               case R.id.button2:
               // do stuff
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                button2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

                button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Login.class);
                                       startActivity(intent);   
                    }
                });
               break;
               case R.id.button3:
                   button3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

                    button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Recovery.class);
                                           startActivity(intent);   
                        }
                    });
                   break;

               case R.id.button4:

                    button4= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

                    button4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                          finish();
                           System.exit(0);


                        }
                    });
                 }  
       }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

what is wrong with the coding?
help me.thanks:)

Comment: What's at com.example.loga.MainActivity line 22?

Comment: problem is in your MainActivity code

Comment: i cant find.Any specific idea?

Answer (score 2):

Check if you are setting correct layout

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);  //<<------ HERE
```

because i can see that in your `onCreateOptionsMenu` and in `onCreate` you are setting two different named layouts if its by mistake...

So set layout on `onCreate` which has the button id `button1`

**EDIT**

In your `MainActivity` change to this if it helps

```
  @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
           switch(v.getId()) {
               case R.id.button1:
              {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity1.class);
                                       startActivity(intent);   
                    
            }
               break;
               case R.id.button2:
               {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Login.class);
                                       startActivity(intent);   
                    }
               
               break;
               case R.id.button3:
                   {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Recovery.class);
                                           startActivity(intent);   
                        }
                    
                   break;

               case R.id.button4:

                   {

                       
                          finish();
                           System.exit(0);


                        }
                   
                 }
```

Comment: what is the line on which you are getting exception ?? line 22 ?? what is it

Comment: private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success"; declared a string to get the JSON response from server

Comment: add your xml file also in your question.. and check activity_login.xml if it has a button and a edittext with id editText1 and button1 otherwise post it with your question

Comment: its great @logurani but see my edited answer it has corrent format because you are getting again your button in your onclick button which is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have a problem on your Layout there's no element named `R.id.button1` on `R.layout.activity_login` so when you call `button1.setOnClickListener` you get the NulPointerException .

Comment: private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success"; declared a string to get the JSON response from server

Comment: and what is your point? A private static string have nothing to do with the XML layout that was not properly designed.

Comment: both my answer and @Shiv answer are probably correct: your XML layout is wrong. Can you post the line 22 of your Activity ?

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

Comment: I just realised, the error is on `MainActivity` and you posted the code for `Login`. What is the line 22 on `MainActivity`  ?

Comment: any ideas to find solutions?

Comment: activity_main.xml has all these buttons??